# What should we be doing, in aspnetcore, instead of setting SuppressAsyncSuffixInActionNames to false?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm working through a tutorial on aspnet core, that is using CreatedAtAction() on POST methods that create objects in the database:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<ItemDto>> PostAsync(CreateItemDto createItemDto)
{
    var item = new Item
    {
        ...
    };

    await itemsRepository.CreateAsync(item);

    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetByIdAsync), new { id = item.Id }, item);
}
```

What this does is to return the object created in the body, and to put a location header in the response:

```
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
date: Wed02 Jun 2021 15:21:13 GMT 
location: https://localhost:5001/items/10189cc2-bb99-4315-9247-a6990bc9563a 
server: Kestrel
```

The author points out that there was a breaking change in aspnetcore 3.0 that required SuppressAsyncSuffixInActionNames to be set to false:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers(options =>
    {
        options.SuppressAsyncSuffixInActionNames = false;
    });

    ...
}
```

If we do not set SuppressAsyncSuffixInActionNames to false, we get an exception in CreatedAtAction():

```
fail: icrosoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
    An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
    System.InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values.
        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CreatedAtActionResult.OnFormatting(ActionContext context)
```

I went looking for info on this and found this discussion:

[[Discussion] Async suffix for controller action names will be trimmed by default #8998](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/8998)

> As part of addressing #4849, ASP.NET Core MVC will trim the suffix Async from action names by default. This affects routing and link generation

Which references this bug:

[Make-method-async code fix breaks ASP.NET MVC action routing after 'Async' suffix is appended to method name #4849](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/4849)

I have to say I don't like the author's solution. Yes, you can restore the old behavior by turning off the change, but doesn't that mean restoring the bug?

We could work around the issue by specifying the URL directly, instead of using nameof(), or by removing "Async" from what is returned by nameof():

```
return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetByIdAsync).Replace("Async", ""), new { id = item.Id }, item);
```

But I'm not sure I like either of these.

How *should* this be fixed? What is recommended?

Comment: If you insist on using `nameof`, I think setting `SuppressAsyncSuffixInActionNames` to false is **more recommended**. In this way you no need **manually remove** the `Async` suffix **every time**.

Answer (score 0):

See the "why" of this change in this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/14716).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31483222)